# How to change the sender of a function call?

Tags: solidity, truffle

I have this code from `truffle unbox metacoin`:

```
ontract('MetaCoin', (accounts) => {
  it('should put 10000 MetaCoin in the first account', async () => {
    const metaCoinInstance = await MetaCoin.deployed();
    const balance = await metaCoinInstance.getBalance.call(accounts[0]);

    assert.equal(balance.valueOf(), 10000, "10000 wasn't in the first account");
  });
```

- Which account has deployed Metacoin? Is it `accounts[0]`?
- How do I change the sender of a call in these tests? I am using the `Owner` contract from open zeppelin and I'd like to test its functionality via a unit test

Comment: Change `MetaCoin.deployed()` to `MetaCoin.new({from: accounts[1]})`, for example.

Comment: @goodvibration ah ok, thank you. Is it true that every subsequent call in the test is made be the owner? If so, how do I change the sender of an arbitrary call? For example, I want accounts[10] to call `getBalance`

Comment: Alternatively, in your (preliminary) deployment script, change `MetaCoin.new()` to `MetaCoin.new({from: accounts[1]})`.

Comment: The default in every function-call via Truffle, is that the object `{from: accounts[0]}` is passed to the function right after the last input argument.

Comment: For example, when you do `myContract.func(1, 2, 3)`, Truffle converts that to `myContract.func(1, 2, 3, {from: accounts[0], value: 0, gas: ..., gasLimit: ...})`.

Comment: You can add that object explicitly, use whichever fields you want to override, and set them to whatever you want. For example:  `myContract.func(1, 2, 3, {from: accounts[1]})`.

Comment: Brilliant - thank you. You can make answer off this so I can accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default in every function-call made via Truffle, is that the object `{from: accounts[0]}` is passed to the function right after the last input argument.

For example, when you call `myContract.func(1, 2, 3)`, Truffle converts that to `myContract.func(1, 2, 3, {from: accounts[0]})`.

You can add that object explicitly and set the calling account to whatever you want, for example: `myContract.func(1, 2, 3, {from: accounts[1]})`.

So in your specific case, you can do either one of the following:

- In your test script, change `MetaCoin.deployed()` to `MetaCoin.new(arg1, arg2, ..., {from: accounts[1]})`
- In your deployment script, change `MetaCoin.new(arg1, arg2, ...)` to `MetaCoin.new(arg1, arg2, ..., {from: accounts[1]})`